# Program for minimal projective resolution

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Hi,

I have the following problem.

> > I am searching for a program that can compute a minimal projective resolution of an arbitrary finitely
> >     generated module of a quotient of a path algebra by an admissible ideal.

I wonder, if this is possible with the program GAP and the package qpa, but on the webpage

http://www.math.ntnu.no/~oyvinso/QPA/

I read:

"One of the major aims is to be able to contruct projective resolutions of finitely generated modules over finite dimensional quotients of path algebras. This is not yet available."

Therefore, I'd like to know, if there is any other program that can do this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: A predecessor of QPA called GRB did exactly this. Send an email to the QPA team and ask.

Comment: I think MAGMA can do this as well.  Read through http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/basic_algebras